# Insert and then update post_type by wp_update_post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, wp-update-post

I wrote a function to insert content in the page and every date update automatic .

I used  `wp_update_post( $my_post );` to update page .

I want first insert content in top specific page and then update, but it isn't working.

it's only updating or inserting content..

```
function wp_emallmobnok(){
        $postdater =  parsidate('j / F / Y',$datetime='now',$lang='pre');
        $postdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $ta = parsidate('j / F / Y',$datetime='now',$lang='pre');
        $postdate_gmt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $titles="price daily";
        $posts = array(

            'post_content'   => $oiobz1,
            'post_name'      => $titles,/// The page url name
            'ID'             => 225, /// The page id witch we want to update that
            'post_title'     => $titles,
            'post_type'      => 'page',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_author'    => '6',
            'ping_status'    => 'open',

            'post_date'  => $postdate_gmt,
            'post_category' => array(188),
            'tags_input'     => " price",
        );


        $post_id = wp_insert_post($posts);//// instert post
        add_post_meta( $post_id, ' wp_insert_post', 0, true );

        $post_up = wp_update_post($posts);///update post
        add_post_meta( $post_id, ' wp_update_post', 0, true );


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Codex says about `wp_update_post`:

> To work as expected, it is necessary to pass the ID of the post to be updated.
>
> Filling out the ID field is not strictly necessary but without it there is little point to using the function.

So you must add newly created post ID to `$posts` to update it.

```
function wp_emallmobnok(){
    $postdater    =  parsidate('j / F / Y',$datetime='now',$lang='pre');
    $postdate     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $ta           = parsidate('j / F / Y',$datetime='now',$lang='pre');
    $postdate_gmt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $titles       ="price daily";

    // Post data
    $posts        = array(
        'post_content'  => $oiobz1,
        'post_name'     => $titles,
        'post_title'    => $titles,
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => '6',
        'ping_status'   => 'open',
        'post_date'     => $postdate_gmt,
        'post_category' => array(188),
        'tags_input'    => " price",
    );


    $post_id = wp_insert_post($posts);//// instert post
    add_post_meta( $post_id, ' wp_insert_post', 0, true );

    // Update post if inserting was successful
    if( $post_id !== 0 && !is_wp_error( $post_id ) ){
      // Add post ID to post data
      $posts['ID'] = intval( $post_id ); // ID has to be integer

      $post_up = wp_update_post($posts);///update post
      add_post_meta( $post_id, ' wp_update_post', 0, true );
    }
    else if( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ){
      $error_string = $post_id->get_error_message();
      echo 'ERROR: '.$error_string;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. sending dublicate post. and no update @Rene Korss

Comment: Check the value of `$post_id` after `$post_id = wp_insert_post($posts);`. Maybe it has some errors. I edited my post to check for errors.

Comment: only publishing duplicate post

Comment: The ID should be integer but in my code was strings. I changed to integer and add 'ID'with number, below 'post_name'.. Thanks very much